# Is there a way to make a class's private methods accessible to another class without nesting it?

Tags: java

I know we can nest a class to access its private fields and methods, like the following example, which compiles fine:

```
public class Outer {
    Inner inner = new Inner();

    public class Inner {
        private Inner() {

        }
    }
}
```

However, what I want to achieve is sort of like this:

```
public class A {
    B b = new B();
}

class B {
    private B() { // error: B() has private access in B

    }
}
```

I know in C++, we can use the `friend` keyword, but I've learned there is no friend or friend equivalent in Java. So how do I achieve that?

`Update #1`: The two code snippets above are not in one Java file. They are just two separate examples. Sorry for the confusion.

`Update #2`: This problem was solved by using packages.

Comment: when you work with `package`s you could make the `B` constructor `package-private` (So just remove the `private`-modifier)

Comment: It's best to avoid declaring more than one top-level class per file.

Comment: Private means private. What you are asking is how can I make a private member not be private. Surely the only answer can be "delete the private keyword".

Comment: @shmosel Thanks for pointing that out. Actually, I didn't put them in one file. They are just two seperate examples. I will update my original post.

Comment: You can create a non private static method in class B that can return a new instance of B to A

Comment: @JosephPeter In that case, every class can have an instance of class B. However, I only want class A to have instances of class B.

Comment: @Lino I have thought about that. But, if I put classes A and B in one package, and write my application in another package but import class B, will I have access to class B's constructor?

Comment: @JosephPeter And I don't want to enclose class B in class A because it will make class A hefty when code gets long.

Comment: @Lino I just experimented on that and it worked, aulthough it requires extra work.

Comment: @OneFlowerOneWorld to your first comment, no you will have not. class `B` will only be available to that package. And to the latter: it actually does not. Java Applications are meant to be split up. And to do that the most efficient way you have to use classes in different packages. So its not really extra work, but just a habit

Comment: @OneFlowerOneWorld Also you might want to post a self answer explaining what you did and what actually solved your problem. E.g. with an additional code snippet. Don't just say it in your question

Answer (score -1):

You need to setup accessor methods to be able to access the private methods in the other class file.

Comment: an accessor method for a method? This approach probably works best for fields only

Comment: @Lino another way could be to use anin

Comment: Sorry I mean to access private variables lol

Answer (score -2):

You can use the static keyword while defining B. Without static, as you have it, B is an inner class; with static, B is a nested class. Nested classes cannot access the private instance fields of the enclosing class, as inner classes can.

You can also change the scope of the B() constructor to default, so that A can see it. However, in my experience, having two top-level types in one file is not done.

Comment: Nested classes can access private members of the enclosing class too. And it is uncommon to have more than one toplevel-class in one file, but can be done.

Comment: I think you summarized my response. Why did you down-vote me?

Comment: `Nested classes cannot access the private instance fields of the enclosing class` - they can.